# Selenide + Junit 5 assertionMode = SOFT doesn't work

Tags: java, junit5, selenide

Well, my problem is when I try to set a Selenide variable assertionMode = SOFT my test is being ignored and Selenide throws an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using soft asserts, but without @SoftAsserts annotation
```

When I use examples from Selenide documentation for instance:

write an annotation above test class

```
@ExtendWith(SoftAssertsExtension.class)
class IssueCreationTest extends BaseTest {

@Test
void test() {...}
}
```

or define SoftAssertsExtension as a class variable

```
class Tests {

@RegisterExtension 
static SoftAssertsExtension softAsserts = new SoftAssertsExtension();

@Test
void test() {...}
}
```

I am getting the same problem.

Maybe somebody came across this problem and maybe someone might know how I could fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Well! When I describe BaseTest as some kind of logic and behavior with the @BeforeAll and @afterall methods that must be done before the start of the test, the script crashes on the very first method ... click (); ... both in the method with the annotation @BeforeAll and @afterall (screenshot with an example below).

[BrokenBaseTest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGuQQ.png)

But if you transfer these steps to the method with the @test annotation in this class or to the methods of the classes that BaseTest will hear ... then everything starts to work and with all the methods described in the documentation (screenshot with an example below).

[WorkedBaseTest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEqQw.png)

The problem is solved, I hope I clearly described the essence. It is not clear only why in the first case Sekenide refuses to work and throws an exception.